# Can I control Windows Setting Focus Assist (On/Off) in my WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, windows-10

I would like to implement a feature in my C# WPF project where within the application a User can turn on/off Focus Assist (a setting within Windows 10) using a checkbox which will automatically switch the Focus Assist Setting to 'On' or if unchecked 'Off'.

If possible I don't want to open the Focus Assist window for the user to click manually on/off.

I've tried searching how to have the ability to control these settings and all I could find was to implement the class `Windows.System`, however, the only controls seems to be for `Windows.System.RemoteDesktop`, `Windows.System.Power`, `Windows.System.Display` and lacking `FocusAssist`.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggling Focus Assist mode in Win 10 Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477041/toggling-focus-assist-mode-in-win-10-programmatically) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510772/activating-focus-assist-windows-10-setting-programmatically