# Activating Focus Assist Windows 10 Setting Programmatically C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I'm building a C# WPF application and want the ability to programmatically enable and disable the Windows System Feature `Focus Assist`.

I've tried researching how to control this feature programmatically but cannot see anything on it (possibly because it's a new system feature). I've seen notes on using the `Windows.System` library however focus assist doesn't seem to apart of it

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: **See Also**: [Toggling Focus Assist mode in Win 10 Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55477041/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following. Tested in Windows 10 22H2 19045.3803.

Notes:

- Under Windows Focus Assist settings, either `When I'm duplicating my display` or `When I'm playing a game` must be set to `On`, depending on which mode you intend to activate programmatically.
- In order to turn Focus Assist on, you sometimes need to issue a command to turn it off first (even though it is already off). For best results, always turn off then on.

  ```
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

   while(true)
   {

       var focusAssistMode = Console.ReadLine() == "on" ? FocusAssistMode.Fullscreen : FocusAssistMode.Off;

       var result = FocusAssistHelper.SetFocusAssistMode(focusAssistMode);

       if (result == 0)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Success");
       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Failed with error code {result}");
       };

   }

   public static class FocusAssistHelper
   {

       [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
       static extern int ZwUpdateWnfStateData(
           ref ulong StateName,
           IntPtr Buffer,
           int Length,
           Guid TypeId,
           IntPtr ExplicitScope,
           uint MatchingChangeStamp,
           bool CheckStamp
       );

       [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
       static extern int ZwQueryWnfStateData(
           ref ulong StateName,
           Guid TypeId,
           IntPtr ExplicitScope,
           out uint ChangeStamp,
           IntPtr Buffer,
           ref int BufferSize
       );

       const ulong WNF_SHEL_QUIET_MOMENT_SHELL_MODE_CHANGED = 0xd83063ea3bf5075UL;

       public static int GetFocusAssistMode(out FocusAssistMode mode)
       {

           var stateName = WNF_SHEL_QUIET_MOMENT_SHELL_MODE_CHANGED;

           int bufferSize = 4;
           var bufferPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);

           var result = ZwQueryWnfStateData(ref stateName, Guid.Empty, IntPtr.Zero, out _, bufferPtr, ref bufferSize);

           if (result == 0)
           {

               var modeAsByteArray = new byte[bufferSize];

               Marshal.Copy(bufferPtr, modeAsByteArray, 0, modeAsByteArray.Length);

               mode = (FocusAssistMode)BitConverter.ToUInt32(modeAsByteArray);

           }
           else
           {
               mode = FocusAssistMode.Off;
           }

           return result;

       }

       public static int SetFocusAssistMode(FocusAssistMode mode)
       {

           var stateName = WNF_SHEL_QUIET_MOMENT_SHELL_MODE_CHANGED;

           var modeAsByteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)mode);

           var bufferPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(modeAsByteArray.Length);

           try
           {

               Marshal.Copy(modeAsByteArray, 0, bufferPtr, modeAsByteArray.Length);

               return ZwUpdateWnfStateData(ref stateName, bufferPtr, modeAsByteArray.Length, Guid.Empty, IntPtr.Zero, 0, false);

           }
           finally
           {
               Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferPtr);
           }

       }

   }

   public enum FocusAssistMode : uint
   {
       Off = 0,
       Game = 1,
       Fullscreen = 2,
   }
  ```